# what is the use of Zone.js in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently am learning **Angular** **2.0** and i come accross the file **Zone.js**, and i would like to know what is the purpose of the file Zone.js and how will it make my application better.

Answer (score 51):

A zone is an execution context that persists across async tasks, and allows the creator of the zone to observe and control execution of the code within the zone.

I think that **the main purpose** of using zonejs in angular2 is **to know when to render**.

According to [NgZone Primer](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F5Ug0jcrm031vhSMJEOgp1l-Is-Vf0UCNDY-LsQtAIY/edit#) (Chapter 5: Use Cases/Use Case 3: Framework Auto Render)

> Frameworks, such as Angular, need to know when all of the application
>   work has completed and perform DOM update before the host environment
>   performs the pixel rendering. In practice this means that the
>   framework is interested when the main task and the associated micro
>   tasks have executed but before the VM hands over the control to the
>   host.

Angular uses the zone to patch async APIs(addEventListener, setTimeout(), ...) and uses notifications from these patched APIs to run change detection every time some async event happened.

For this Angular zone has `onMicrotaskEmpty` event

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.2.4/modules/%40angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L199

and `ApplicationRef` subscribes to this event to trigger change detection (`Application.tick`)

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.2.4/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L405-L406

Also zonejs is useful for debugging, testing, profiling. It helps you see whole call stack if you face with some error.

Zone patches async APIs like:

```
Promise
XHR
fetch
Error
addEventListener
removeEventListener
FileReader
WebSocket
MutationObserver
WebKitMutationObserver
document.registerElement
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

copy cut paste abort blur focus canplay canplaythrough change click contextmenu 
dblclick drag dragend dragenter dragleave dragover dragstart drop 
durationchange emptied ended input invalid keydown keypress keyup 
load loadeddata loadedmetadata loadstart message 
mousedown mouseenter mouseleave mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup 
pause play playing progress ratechange reset scroll 
seeked seeking select show stalled submit suspend 
timeupdate volumechange waiting 
mozfullscreenchange mozfullscreenerror mozpointerlockchange 
mozpointerlockerror error webglcontextrestored webglcontextlost webglcontextcreationerror

setTimeout/clearTimeout
setInterval/clearInterval
setImmediate/clearImmediate

requestAnimationFrame/cancelAnimationFrame
mozRequestAnimationFrame/mozCancelAnimationFrame
webkitRequestAnimationFrame/webkitCancelAnimationFrame

alert
prompt
confirm
```

This articles might be usefull to understand how it works in angular2

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html
- http://blog.kwintenp.com/how-the-hell-do-zones-really-work/

Answer (score 16):

**Zone.js** is the key to Angular's change detection.

Zone creates a wrapper around all **asynchronous operations** in the browser such as **user interactions, HTTP, timers** and any other changes that can cause changes in state.

Zone knows when any these operations completes. Angular in-turn, **subscribes to notifications** from Zone for whenever one of these operations completes. This lets Angular know that it can run its **change detection** algorithms and re-render anything that has changed.

This minimizes any rendering churn and makes it efficient.

Answer (score 13):

Zonejs is one of the core library used in Angularjs 2. Zonejs is to maintain contextual execution for single or multi-leveled asynchronous methods. So, it means it helps to keep track of the parent context of currently executing asynchronous method.

Example -

```js
Zone.current.fork({}).run(function(){
 Zone.current.myZoneVar = true;
 console.log('Assigned myZoneVar');
 setTimeout(()=>{
   console.log('In timeout', Zone.current.myZoneVar);
 },1000);
});
console.log('Out side', Zone.current.myZoneVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser"></script>
```

Note : Plz, ignore the console error. This code working fine in jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/subhadipghosh/0uqc9rdr/

Here we created a fork of our current Zone and run is invoking the method under the Zone. The method has an asynchronous call (setTimeout). But as it is under zone we have the access of Zone variable. In last line we can see out of zone we are trying to access same variable, but it will have undefined in it.

Original post - http://technobelities.blogspot.in/2017/03/zonejs-overview-with-example.html

Angular 2 is utilizing Zonejs for change detection. Whenever any change happens, it is detected by following code in Angular 2 -

```
ObservableWrapper.subscribe(this.zone.onTurnDone, () => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.tick();
  });
});

tick() {
  // perform change detection
  this.changeDetectorRefs.forEach((detector) => {
    detector.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

Angular zone emits onTurnDone event to start change detection in the app.

Answer (score 7):

**In simple language Zone.js is a api or set of programs which is used by angular 2 to update the application view when any change occurred.**

A Zone is an execution context that persists across asynchronous task.
 **for example**:Events, XMLHttpRequests and Timers(setTimeout(), setInterval()) etc.

Answer (score 3):

Zone.js uses for async calls and internally for the error and stack trace angular 2 is using it. So you cannot ignore this script.