# What does hasPendingMacrotasks and hasPendingMicrotasks check for?

Tags: javascript, angular

What is the difference between hasPendingMacrotasks or hasPendingMicrotasks within NgZone? The documentation seems to be lacking information. All I know is that they return a boolean. But what exactly are they checking for? What is considered a micro task? And what is considered a macro task?

```
class NgZone {
  static isInAngularZone() : boolean
  static assertInAngularZone() : void
  static assertNotInAngularZone() : void
  constructor({enableLongStackTrace = false}: any)
  run(fn: () => any) : any
  runGuarded(fn: () => any) : any
  runOutsideAngular(fn: () => any) : any
  onUnstable : EventEmitter<any>
  onMicrotaskEmpty : EventEmitter<any>
  onStable : EventEmitter<any>
  onError : EventEmitter<any>
  isStable : boolean
  hasPendingMicrotasks : boolean
  hasPendingMacrotasks : boolean
}
```

My best guess is that micro refers to tasks from within a specific class whereas macro probably refers to a task in regards to the whole application. Can anyone verify or confirm this assumption? Or shed some light on the specifics?

**NgZone Docs:**

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html#!#hasPendingMicrotasks-anchor

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**There are three kinds of tasks**

1) **MicroTask**:

A microtask is work which will execute as soon as possible on empty stack frame. A microtask is guaranteed to run before host environment performs rendering or I/O operations. A microtask queue must be empty before another MacroTask or EventTask runs.

i.e. `Promise.then()` executes in microtask

2) **MacroTask**

MacroTasks are interleaved with rendering and I/O operations of the host environment. They are guaranteed to run at least once or canceled (some can run repeatedly such as `setInterval`). Macro tasks have an implied execution order.

i.e. `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `setImmediate`

3) **EventTask**

EventTasks are similar to macro tasks, but unlike macro tasks they may never run. When an EventTask is run, it pre-empts whatever the next task is the macro task queue. Event tasks do not create a queue.

i.e. user `click`, `mousemove`, `XHR` state change.

**Why is it useful to know if any of the tasks are currently being performed?**

- Knowing when a task has executed and a microtask queue is empty allows frameworks to know when it is time to render the UI.
- Tracking when all scheduled tasks are executed allows a test framework to know when an asynchronous test has completed.

**ng_zone.ts**

```
private checkStable() {
  if (this._nesting == 0 && !this._hasPendingMicrotasks && !this._isStable) {
    try {
      this._nesting++;
      this._onMicrotaskEmpty.emit(null);
    } finally {
      this._nesting--;
      if (!this._hasPendingMicrotasks) {
        try {
          this.runOutsideAngular(() => this._onStable.emit(null));
        } finally {
          this._isStable = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

See also

- [what is the use of Zone.js in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902572/what-is-the-use-of-zone-js-in-angular-2)

Comment: Is there any way to do cancel the macro and micro tasks in zone.js?