# Do all setInterval functions trigger change detection?

Tags: angular

Per the title, I am curious if every time I create an interval with `setInterval` if, because of the shimming done by Angular, if this creates a change detection event every time the interval runs.

I've been reading all the documentation I can find, but I can't find a clear answer on this.

for clarification, my question is, if I ran the following code, would every iteration of the interval trigger a change detection event and cause Angular to attempt to update the view of the application until the conditions are met?

```
let myInterval = setInterval( () => {

    if (conditionsAreMet()){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
})
```

Comment: Every async event triggers change detection AFAIK. Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40903120/5706293 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43480931/5706293

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what zone this `setInterval` is used. If it's used inside NgZone, then yes, it will trigger change detection every time. If you run it outside angular zone, it won't trigger change detection.

Outside Angular zone:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(zone: NgZone) {
    // will not trigger change detection
    zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.name = 'boob';
      }, 2000);
    })
```

Inside Angular zone:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(zone: NgZone) {
    // will trigger change detection
    setInterval(() => {
      this.name = 'boob';
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: So if it is inside a component being loaded by the Angular application, it will trigger change detection?

Comment: @StephenRios, it depends on how you use it. In my first example it's launched from inside the component, but outside Angular zone. But in general, yes, if you simply use `setInterval` inside a component's methods that are hooks or methods that react to events, it will schedule a change detection cycle

Comment: I think the second example's "will not trigger" is a typo, and is supposed to be "will trigger".  That's the whole point, right?  (I was going to edit it myself but I want to be 100% sure I understand it first.)